# Two OnClickListeners for one Button

Tags: android, event-handling, buttonclick, onclicklistener

How would I go about creating more than one `OnClickListener` for one `Button`. Suppose I have an application that starts recording audio on the first click and stops recording on the next click. How would I go about doing that ?

I tried using two `OnClickListeners` but that didn't work.

**EDIT**

I am trying to make some more implementations to my current app. I am trying to change the text on the button during run time if the audio is recording. I would like the text on the button to say Recording.. and after 1 second it should say Recording... . This should happen the entire time while the audio is recording . I tried implementing this but I couldn't get it to work. Here is my code:

```
audio.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        
        
 if(audioRecording == false){
     audio.setText("Recording..");
     startRecording(); 
     audioRecording = true;
     
        while(!audio.isPressed()){
          audio.setText("Recording...");
         try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        attachVoice.setText("Recording..");
          }

     
 }
 
 else{
     audio.setText("Press to Record");
     stopRecording(); 
     audioRecording = false;
     
 }
    
            
    }
});
```

Comment: The last part about the `Button` having the text *Recording...* and one second later having the same text *Recording...* doesn't make any sense(and you shouldn't be using `Thread.sleep(2000);
` there). Are you trying by any chance to make the `Button` to have a blinking text effect(like the `Recording...` text appearing and disappearing at a 1 second interval?)?

Comment: @AndroidDev93 you should not edit your question and make it into something completely different. You should have started a new question, you've now made the answers below irrelevant for anyone else coming across this question. That is not the way the stackoverflow community works.

Comment: @Luksprog - I am not trying to have a blinking text effect.  The button has the text "Recording ..." and one second later it has the text Recording ..". It has one period less. Let me try to be a bit more clear. While recording the audio I want to change the text on the button every second. I have 2 texts A and B. Suppose the text on the button is A, I want that text to stay on the button for 1 second and then change to B and that cycle will continue.

Comment: I've edited my answer, see if that is what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it loads of ways, the point is you somehow have to save the state of your application. Here is a simple example:

```
boolean audioRecording = false;

public void onButtonClick(View v){
     if(audioRecording){
         stopRecording();
         audioRecording = false;
     } else {
         recordAudio();
         audioRecording = true;
     }
}
```

Comment: On the plus side, your code has more meaningful names:)

Answer (score 5):

Just implement a flag so you know in what state you are:

```
boolean status = true;
//...

//the Button OnCLickListener callback
public void onClick(View v) {
     if (status) {
        //start the player
        status = false;
     } else {
        // stop the player
        status = true;
     }
}
```

**Edit :**

See if the code below helps:

```
boolean playerStatus = true;
boolean updaterStatus = true;
String[] recStrings = { "Recording..", "Recording.........." };
int i = 0;

// ...
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Button b = (Button) v;
                if (playerStatus) {
                    playerStatus = false;
                    // start player
                    updaterStatus = true;
                    updateButton(b);
                } else {
                    // end player
                    playerStatus = true;
                    updaterStatus = false;
                    b.setText("Not recording");
                }
            }
        });
```

and the `updateButton` method:

```
private void updateButton(final Button btn) {
        if (updaterStatus) {
            btn.setText(recStrings[i % 2]);
            i++;
            btn.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateButton(btn);
                }

            }, 1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: got there 48 seconds before me, funny how similar our code is, great minds think alike :p

Answer (score 0):

For what you explained the button should be a two state button, like a checkbox, you can change the drawables associated with the checkbox, look here for that:

http://www.anddev.org/tutorial_change_look_of_checkbox-t4553.html

Basically with the checkbox in the onClick method you check if the check box is clicked and do one method else do the other

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked())
            method1();
        else
            method2();
    }

    private void method2() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void method1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Comment: If that `onClick` is for a checkbox you can just cast the `View v` paramater to the check box

Comment: True that, ill add it in

Comment: Opsie daisy, forgot about that sorry